# How to chain multiple different InputStreams into one InputStream

Tags: java, scala, io, inputstream

I'm wondering if there is any ideomatic way to chain multiple InputStreams into one continual InputStream in Java (or Scala).

What I need it for is to parse flat files that I load over the network from an FTP-Server. What I want to do is to take file[1..N], open up streams and then combine them into one stream. So when file1 comes to an end, I want to start reading from file2 and so on, until I reach the end of fileN.

I need to read these files in a specific order, data comes from a legacy system that produces files in barches so data in one depends on data in another file, but I would like to handle them as one continual stream to simplify my domain logic interface.

I searched around and found PipedInputStream, but I'm not positive that is what I need. An example would be helpful.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you merge two input streams in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/760228/how-do-you-merge-two-input-streams-in-java)

Answer (score 113, accepted):

It's right there in JDK! Quoting [JavaDoc of `SequenceInputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/SequenceInputStream.html):

> A `SequenceInputStream` represents the logical concatenation of other input streams. It starts out with an ordered collection of input streams and reads from the first one until end of file is reached, whereupon it reads from the second one, and so on, until end of file is reached on the last of the contained input streams.

You want to concatenate arbitrary number of `InputStream`s while `SequenceInputStream` accepts only two. But since `SequenceInputStream` is also an `InputStream` you can apply it recursively (nest them):

```
new SequenceInputStream(
    new SequenceInputStream(
        new SequenceInputStream(file1, file2),
        file3
    ),
    file4
);
```

...you get the idea.

## See also

- [How do you merge two input streams in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/760228) (dup?)

Comment: Doh! I must have really bad luck with my keywords when googling today. Because I gave it a good googling. I figured that I can't really be the first one needing this, thanks!

Comment: SequenceInputStream constructor also accepts a Enumeration, so you don't have to do the nesting.

Comment: Are they any concerns if I chain hundreds of inputstreams using this technique?

Comment: @pretzels1337, a bit late. yes there is a concern : you will open all files at once, when creating the enumeration of inputstream, and there is a limit to the number of files that can be opened concurrently (set by the OS). For this use case, I would rather copy the SequenceInputStream code, replace the `Enumeration<InputStream>` with `List<File>`, and alter the `nextStream()` and `close()` methods accordingly. You could provide your own `Enumeration<InputStream>` that opens the stream in `nextElement()`, but look at what will happen in `close()` in case of IOExcpetion on the first inputstream

Comment: Can I seek to random position in SequenceInputStream? I mean forward and backward.

Answer (score 16):

This is done using SequencedInputStream, which is straightforward in Java, as Tomasz Nurkiewicz's answer shows.  I had to do this repeatedly in a project recently, so I added some Scala-y goodness via the "pimp my library" pattern.

```
object StreamUtils {
  implicit def toRichInputStream(str: InputStream) = new RichInputStream(str)

  class RichInputStream(str: InputStream) {
// a bunch of other handy Stream functionality, deleted

    def ++(str2: InputStream): InputStream = new SequenceInputStream(str, str2)
  }
}
```

With that, I can do stream sequencing as follows

```
val mergedStream = stream1++stream2++stream3
```

or even

```
val streamList = //some arbitrary-length list of streams, non-empty
val mergedStream = streamList.reduceLeft(_++_)
```

Answer (score 16):

Another solution: first create a list of input stream and then create the sequence of input streams:

```
List<InputStream> iss = Files.list(Paths.get("/your/path"))
        .filter(Files::isRegularFile)
        .map(f -> {
            try {
                return new FileInputStream(f.toString());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        }).collect(Collectors.toList());

new SequenceInputStream(Collections.enumeration(iss)))
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a more elegant solution using Vector, this is for Android specifically but use vector for any Java

```
    AssetManager am = getAssets();
    Vector v = new Vector(Constant.PAGES);
    for (int i =  0; i < Constant.PAGES; i++) {
        String fileName = "file" + i + ".txt";
         InputStream is = am.open(fileName);
         v.add(is);
    }
    Enumeration e = v.elements();
    SequenceInputStream sis = new SequenceInputStream(e);
    InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(sis);

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(isr);   // or use bufferedReader
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple Scala version that concatenates an `Iterator[InputStream]`:

```
import java.io.{InputStream, SequenceInputStream}
import scala.collection.JavaConverters._

def concatInputStreams(streams: Iterator[InputStream]): InputStream =
  new SequenceInputStream(streams.asJavaEnumeration)
```