# java inputstream (add header and footer)

Tags: java, inputstream

I would like to write a piece of java which adds a header and a footer to an inputstream .

```
public static InputStream enrichInputStream(InputStream is,
                                            String header,
                                            String footer) {
   ...
}
```

Imagine you have an Inputstream from which you would get: "HERE IS SOME DATA"

then if I were calling

```
enrich(is,"my-header","my-footer")
```

I would get

```
my-headerHERE IS SOME DATAmy-footer
```

is this doable ?
Can somebody sketch a solution ?

p.s.
Note: the inputstream might be very large so it's not a good solution to combine header + content of the original InputSTream + footer together...

Comment: how big is your inputstream roughly?

Comment: @Bohemian Good Point. It's massive !!!

Comment: Too big to keep in memory? Is it more than a few Mb?

Comment: @Bohemian Precisely so. Besides the user of the InputStream might be happy with reading just a few chunks ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about SequenceInputStream to joint your header, body and footer together.

See here: [how-to-chain-multiple-different-inputstreams-into-one-inputstream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14295099/how-to-chain-multiple-different-inputstreams-into-one-inputstream)

Comment: Olschewsky That's sounds an elegant solution... let me look into

Comment: @Zo72 it basically does `combine header + content of the original InputStream + footer` which you never wanted right?

Answer (score 2):

Sketch of solution, as requested by the question:
Create your own class, EnrichedInputStream, inheriting from InputStream.

1. Remember header, footer, and teh original stream in the constructor call which has these three as parameters.
2. Have one or more instance variables showing state (position in header, in original stream, in footer.
3. Owerwrite the read function to first deliver the header, after its end, pass on the contentz of the original stream, after its end deliver the footer. This would make use of the above mentioned instance variables.

Comment: @FrankPI that's fair... but it seems quite hard... I wonder if there is something simpler

Comment: +1 I think this simple, pretty easy to implement and lightweight

Comment: That would be less than fifty lines of code, I would assume. But simpler that that, I do not think it is possible in Java.

Comment: @FrankPI no the solution by Fank Olschewsky is better

Comment: Yes, you are right. And internally, the `SequenceInputStream` is implemented similar to what I described, see http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7-b147/java/io/SequenceInputStream.java

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do this with the way you describe by a method call. You must write the header, then the data, then the footer.

You need to create a filtered stream, by extending `FilterInputStream` or for output, `FilterOutputStream`.

You may then override methods such as `read(` in order to read the header first.

For output, this is somewhat easier. Simply write the header on opening the stream and override `close(` to write the footer before closing.