# How can you read multiple objects into a single ObjectInputStream?

Tags: java, file, stream, objectinputstream, objectoutputstream

Before sending a file to a remote machine, I'm sharding it into multiple smaller pieces locally.

Once the file is split into shards, I write the objects using and `ObjectOutputStream`.
Can I read multiple `shard` objects from file, using a `ObjectInputStream`, into a single object? I see no immediate way to *append* to the `ObjectInputStream`.

So basically, the flow I'm hoping to have would go:

- Shard File

  - Split file into multiple shards
  - Write each shard using `ooo.writeObject(shard)`
  - (e.g., shard.1, shard.2, shard.3, ...)
- Merge File

  - From a list of shard files, use an `ObjectInputStream` to read/combine them back into their original object.

Comment: There is SequenceInputStream to string multiple InputStreams together. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14295099/how-to-chain-multiple-different-inputstreams-into-one-inputstream

Answer (score 0):

Use the same `ObjectInputStream` and `ObjectOutputStream` for the entire transmission. Then you can write and read as many objects with them as you like.

OR

Use a new `ObjectInputStream` per `ObjectOutputStream.`